# Error while executing some Puppet conditional code

Tags: puppet

I have the following conditional statements. However, every time I have an `elseif` followed by something I seem to get an error:

```
Error: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at 'in'; expected ')' at /etc/puppet/manifests/hash.pp:78 on node puppetmaster
Error: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at 'in'; expected ')' at /etc/puppet/manifests/hash.pp:78 on node puppetmaster


76 if $::operatingsystem in [ 'Ubuntu', 'Debian' ] {
77   notify { 'Debian-type operating system detected': }
78 } elseif $::operatingsystem in [ 'RedHat', 'Fedora', 'SuSE', 'CentOS' ] {
79   notify { 'RedHat-type operating system detected': }
80 } else {
81   notify { 'Some other operating system detected': }
82 }
```

Comment: You don't need the curly braces around if/else code blocks.

Comment: Also, it's `elsif`, not `elseif`.

Comment: And you need an `end` at the end of the whole `if`.

Comment: What does `$::operatingsystem in [ 'Ubuntu', 'Debian' ]` do? Doesn't look like standard ruby.

Comment: Thanks changing it to elsif worked

Comment: elsif $::operatingsystem in [ 'RedHat', 'Fedora', 'SuSE', 'CentOS' ]  checks the the output of $::operatingsystem fact and returns RedHat as the output of applying this manifest returns: Notice: Special manifest for RedHat-like systems

Comment: @SergioTulentsev This is not Ruby. This is Puppet. Coincidentally, both use `elsif` so you did fix his problem and should convert your comment into an answer. However, a quick google would have fixed his problem too. Editing his question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `elsif` instead of `elseif`. Using `elseif` is equivalent to `"elseif"`, and there is no way for puppet to know your intention:

```
if $::operatingsystem in [ 'Ubuntu', 'Debian' ] {
  notify{ 'Debian-type operating system detected': }
} elsif $::operatingsystem in [ 'RedHat', 'Fedora', 'SuSE', 'CentOS' ] {
  notify{'RedHat-type operating system detected': }
} else {
  notify{'Some other operating system detected': }
}
```